# Fast way of generating non-repeating bytes in a random reproducible order

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, random, lookup

I need a fast way to generate 256 rows, each with 256 random bytes and no duplicates.

The lookup tables are generated in such way the element in the first table points to the element from the 2nd table that points to the one in the 1st table, but that's not the point.

This is what I have so far (kinda slow, especially the **while (random_int >= (int)unused.size())** part):

```
unsigned char lookup_table[256 * 256];
unsigned char lookup_table_inverted[256 * 256];

std::vector<unsigned char> unused;
std::mt19937_64 rng(seed);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 255);
int random_int;

for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 256; ++j)
    {
        unused.push_back((unsigned char)j);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 256; ++j)
    {
        random_int = dist(rng);
        while (random_int >= (int)unused.size())
        {
            random_int = dist(rng);
        }

        lookup_table[(i * 256) + j] = unused[random_int];
        lookup_table_inverted[(i * 256) + unused[random_int]] = (unsigned char)j;
        unused.erase(unused.begin() + random_int);
    }
}
```

SOLVED: Using [`std::shuffle()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) and [`std::iota()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).

Comment: "Random reproducible"?  Is that like "airline food" or "military intelligence"?

Comment: `iota` + `shuffle` with a faster PRNG seems much easier, shorter, and eliminates the loop you pointed out. Your question is unlikely to stay open unless you qualify "fast" though, IMO.

Comment: They need to be random but the resulting lookup tables need to be the same every time the same seed is used to seed the random number generator.

Comment: @TypicalHog: Any PRNG which is fast enough will do then.

Comment: PRNG is not my concern. I'm mostly concerned about erasing items from vector and that loop which is generating random numbers until it generates one that wasn't already used. Also, by fast I mean faster than it is currently.

Comment: As already said, just use `std::shuffle`. You already demonstrated how to build a far less efficient duplicate.

Comment: Certainly you can remove your while loop by just doing `dist(rng) % 256`. Or possibly even split the int in to multiple bytes to reduce `dist()` calls.

Comment: @Graeme : Using `uniform_distribution` in conjunction with modulus is really, _really_ missing the big picture. ;-]

Comment: I'm pretty sure modulus makes it biased towards zero as well.?

Comment: @TypicalHog, actually not with 256, you are just masking off bits. `& 0xff` would be equivalent. Either way, shuffle is definitely a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the standard algorithms, specifically [`std::shuffle()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) and [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).
Don't try to bake your own, it's error-prone and likely inefficient.

```
unsigned char lookup_table[256 * 256];
unsigned char lookup_table_inverted[256 * 256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
     auto start = lookup_table + 256 * i;
     std::iota(start, start + 256, 0);
     std::shuffle(start, start + 256, rng);
     auto rev = lookup_table_inverted + 256 * i;
     for (int c = 0; c < 256; ++c)
         rev[start[c]] = c;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `std::shuffle` maybe something like this:

```
std::array<unsigned char, 256> get_random_bytes(int seed = 0)
{
    thread_local static std::mt19937 mt{std::random_device{}()};

    if(seed)
        mt.seed(seed);

    std::array<unsigned char, 256> bytes;

    // fill with the full range of values
    std::iota(std::begin(bytes), std::end(bytes), 0);
    std::shuffle(std::begin(bytes), std::end(bytes), mt); // randomly shuffle them

    return bytes;
}
```

If you supply the function with a non-zero argument it is used to seed the PRNG making the results reproducable.